# Which of the choices displayed is not a possible order in which Depth-First search could mark the vertices of the graph displayed as visited?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

Which of the choices displayed is not a possible order in which Depth-First search could mark the vertices of the graph displayed as visited ?

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a homework problem to me.
Anyways, the answer would be (D), as vertex 'c' has to be visited before vertex 'b' This is because while recursing, when the root is set to be vertex 'd' all of its children ('c') have to be visited before we can visit the next child ('b') of the parent node ('a').